# ¿Cómo ejecutar una función Python cada hora en Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux

Estoy programando una web con Django, y necesito ejecutar una función de Python cada hora para leer un fichero automáticamente.

He probado utilizando `/etc/crontab` y `crontab -e`, pero no me funciona.

¿Hay alguna función de python que me permita ejecutar mi función cada hora?
Gracias por adelantado :)

Comment: Usa **python-crontab** o una libreria cron parecida, para formar el codigo de tiempo cron te recomiendo esta pagina [cron-guru](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: `crontab` debería funcionar sin problemas. Sólo tienes que tener en cuenta que los comandos ejecutados por cron no lo son dentro de un shell, por lo que no tienes acceso a las variables de entorno, entre ellas el PATH. Debes porner por tanto la ruta completa hasta el ejecutable python. Pero te funcionará aún si ese ejecutable está dentro de un entorno virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Yo uso mucho el crontab para ejecutar mis scripts de python, la manera en que funciona para ejecutar cada hora es:

1. Ejecuta `crontab -e`
2. En el editor de `crontab` escribe:

   0 * * * * python [ruta completa hacia tu script]

El 0 indica que el script se ejecutará a cada hora en punto, y los demás parámetros indican que la ejecución sea todos días, semanas y meses.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así:

Primero dándole un `chmod +x /home/user/python_script` para que el fichero pueda ejecutarse.

```
0 0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 * * * /home/user/python_script
```

o en las nuevas versiones:

```
* */1 * * * * /home/user/python_script
```

los valores se toman de izquierda a derecha como:

```
 ┌────────── minutos (0 - 59)
 │ ┌──────── horas (0 - 23)
 │ │ ┌────── dia de del mes (1 - 31)
 │ │ │ ┌──── mes(1 - 12)
 │ │ │ │ ┌── dia de la semana (0 - 6 => domingo- sabado, o
 │ │ │ │ │                1 - 7 => lunes - domingos)
 ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
 * * * * * comando a ejecutar
```

días de la semana por números o por la abreviatura en inglés:

```
0 - Sun      Domingo
1 - Mon      Lunes
2 - Tue      Martes
3 - Wed      Miércoles
4 - Thu      Jueves
5 - Fri      Viernes
6 - Sat      Sabado
7 - Sun      Domingo
```

Comment: las expresiones de cron no son equivalentes. Además, si quieres decir 0, 1, ..., 12 simplemente di `0-12`. Aunque de hecho si quieres indicar cada hora con `*` es suficiente, `*/1` es algo redundante. Prueba con https://crontab.guru para validar las expresiones